# How to set num of session tickets in TLS 1.3 Java

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, openssl, tls1.3

I have a Java server-client application.

```
Client:
SSL connect
SSL_write data
SSL_shutdown
TCP close socket

Server:
SSL accept
SSL read
close socket
```

Above design worked fine.Till we upgraded to TLS 1.3. Now this does not work. when the client closes socket, the server is unable to read the data and throws an exception. (From various articles I read, I figured this may be because the server is still sending session tickets by the time the client closes socket)

I also saw that in Open SSL C++, we can disable the num of tickets and get the above design working. However, I don't see a way to do the same in Java. It looks like it is not permitted at all in the Java TLS lib.

Please let me know if there is a way to disable session tickets (or set num of tickets to 0) in Java. I am using Java 8u261.

(Note: I tried waiting for server socket close before the client closes its socket and that works. However due to some other requirements we have, I am trying to avoid this approach as much as possible)

Comment: The client looks like openssl to me, not Java. 'TCP close socket' should be 'SSL close socket'. Get rid of the shutdown. Then it should work.

Comment: Yes. Client is in C++. Open SSL. the server is in Java and I guess that is where we need to set the num of tickets, isn't it?

Comment: @user207421: didn't get you. what is the difference between TCP close socket and SSL close socket? We are doing a SSL_shutdown which I thought closes the SSL connection.

Comment: That's not what it says in the [documentatipon](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_shutdown.html). Based on that I would do `SSL_shutdown()`, then an `SSL_read()`, which will return EOS but will also consume all the pending messages, then the close.

Comment: @Omi: see the part in the [documentation of SSL_shutdown](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_shutdown.html) which starts with *"When a client only writes and never reads from the connection,  ...."*. This is obviously the relevant scenario here. The exception you get is because you close the socket on the client side before reading all data send by the server (notably the TLS session ticket) - leading the client to send a TCP reset back. You could probably also avoid sending this TCP reset by doing a TCP shutdown with SHUT_RDWR after the SSL shutdown and before the TCP socket close.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That will only cause the *server* to get a connection reset. It won't stop the server sending the tickets, as it won't know about the read shutdown. He needs the final `SSL_read()`.

Comment: @user207421: Correct. Preventing sending the TCP reset by using TCP shutdown is more a quick and dirty work around. The real fix is to do a complete SSL shutdown, which means doing a SSL_read on the client side until the SSL shutdown from the server was received.

Comment: @user207421: we are already doing a tcp shutdown with SHUT_RDWR after the SSL shutdown and before TCP socket close. BTW: if we do tcp shutdown with SHUT_RD that should allow the server to continue reading from the socket, isn't it?

Comment: @Omi Read what I wrote. Call `SSL_shutdown()` and then `SSL_read()`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich TCP shutdown does not reliably prevent a TCP reset. The effect of read shutdown on the sender varies across platforms, but one of them is to *issue* a reset if further data arrives.